# Find the sum of all the primes below two million. why doesn't my code work?

Tags: c, numbers, primes

It should print 142,913,828,922, (and not 1179908154 how it does...)
what's wrong?

http://pastebin.com/gJL4cMxm#

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n=2000000;
    long long sum=0;
    int m;
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(m=2;m<=sqrt(i);m++)
        {
            if(i%m==0)
            {      
                break;
            }
        }
        if(m>sqrt(i))
            sum+=i;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);  
    getch();
}
```

Comment: The problem `"%d"` and `long long` should have been warned by your compiler.  Insure your compiler warning are fully enabled.

Answer (score 5):

**Change:**

```
printf("%d",sum);
```

**To:**

```
printf("%lld",sum);
```

**Explanation:**

If the size of variable `sum` is 4 bytes **or less**, 4 bytes of data are pushed into the stack before `printf` is called.

If the size of variable `sum` is 8 bytes, 8 bytes of data are pushed into the stack before `printf` is called.

After that, `printf("%d"...)` will attempt to read 4 bytes of data from the stack.

The size of type `long long` is 8 bytes on some compilers (including yours probably), hence `print("%d",sum)` prints only "the lower half" of `sum`, which is obviously the wrong value in your perspective (unless `sum` < 2^32).

Comment: `The size of variable sum is 8 bytes`: not necessary!

Comment: No. Change it to that; *the correct specifier for `long long` type is `%ld`. Using a wrong specifier invokes undefined behavior*. Size is implementation defined.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies in the line:

```
printf ("%d\n", sum);
```

It should be like :

```
printf ("%lld\n", sum);
```